# Optional Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ipad

I have an application containing a variety of view controllers linked together in different ways (Welcome > Browse > Preview OR Browse > Preview OR Settings > Splash). The first view controller is presented modally using a navigation controller from a main controller, then the next set of view controllers are added using pop and push.

This works correctly, but I need to be able to define my 'UINavigationBar' and 'UIToolbar' within interface builder, so they still work as expected if they are presented without using a navigation controller. Is this possible? Currently I get this if I try:

[alt text http://xs.to/image-CD8B_4B9E739D.jpg](http://xs.to/image-CD8B_4B9E739D.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in code.

In the SDK it appears you're using, it is fairly trivial to test whether you need to push onto a nav controller or not, and if you are hide the toolbar and adjust the view size to account for that (a custom init method for the view controller will help with this, and if you're particularly smart with how you do things you could even declare a category on UIViewController)